# fullCalendar List View Failing to Display

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm adding fullcalendar to my website to display a variety of upcoming events. I wish to use a "bootstrap tab box" (tabs to switch between different sections of html) to display the calendar in a normal calendar view and a list view. I have implemented it in the way I think is correct and the calendar view displays perfectly, however the list view doesn't. When the tab is displayed the interface loads, but the month's events aren't displayed until you skip forwards a month then back again. I cannot find any fixes for this and I am completely stumped on why it isn't working. I have tried loads of different methods, but have now exhausted myself of all ideas. Do you know how I can fix this?
 [image]

```
<!-- fullCalendar 2.2.5-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">

<!-- fullCalendar 2.2.5 -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Calendar View</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" onclick="RenderList()">List View</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
        <div class="calendar" id="calendarView"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
        <div class="calendar" id="calendarList"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.tab-content -->
  </div>

<script>
function RenderList(){
    $('#calendarList').fullCalendar('changeView', 'listMonth');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        //Options for Both Calendars
        events: [
            {
                title: 'My Birthday',
                start  : '2017-01-05',
                end    : '2017-01-07'
            }  
        ],
    });

    $('#calendarView').fullCalendar({
       //Options for Calendar View 
    });

    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //Options
        //firstDay: 1
    //});

});
</script>
```

**Update**

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendarView').fullCalendar({
        //Options for Calendar View
        events: [
            {
                title: 'My Birthday',
                start  : '2017-01-05',
                end    : '2017-01-07'
            }  
        ],
    });

    $('#calendarList').fullCalendar({
        //Options for Calendar View
        defaultView: 'listMonth',
        events: [
            {
                title: 'My Birthday',
                start  : '2017-01-05',
                end    : '2017-01-07'
            }  
        ],
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You uncommented line `firstDay: 1` maybe this causes the issue check console in browser

Comment: I just re-commented it, however there is no error message with or without it commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the calendar instance defined for .calendar with the one which is defined for #calendarView. You don't have any events in the #calendarView instance. That's why you don't see anything in list view (or may be you have javascript error, because DOM has been changed already - check your console).

You can not extend the calendars in the way you are trying to do. I would suggest to move all common parameters as a constant and provide them to both calendar instances. In addition to initialize calendars for both cases use #calendarView and #calendarList

In addition your version of fullCalendar is 2.2.5. listView is added in 3.0.0 (Reference: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v3.0.0). So you need to update your callendar version.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't get it to work from what I gathered from your post. I've updated the code in my answer with what I have changed it to, however it still doesn't work. Could you give me some example code please to better explain what you mean.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Did you updated RenderList function? This function should switch tabs only. The calendars are already initialized.

Comment: I've completely removed the function. The whole reason I added it was because I thought that it wasn't working because it was wasn't initializing as it wasn't visible on page loading. There is no actual error in the console.

Comment: I tried the code. You have a problem with fullcalendar version. It is 2.2.5. listView is not available in 2.5. Update it to 3 or use the other views.

Comment: I am currently using 3.0 or greater and I just downloaded the version through your link and it still does not work with the code under the Update subtitle. I've made a quick video to show the issue, hopefully it will ensure you understand the issue I'm having. https://youtu.be/gIZcsVHnZMk Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can check working code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4SmWto0pipjRog5Z3vMQ?p=preview. 

I think you resolved all the issues with fullcallendar. I suppose the problem you have now is different (at least this is what I can see on the video).

Comment: I think the plugin doesn't like 2 calendars one one page, or doesn't like the tabs. I have began cutting down an example make by the plugin developers that has a built in function to switch between the views. The only downside is that it doesn't look as good as the tabs I was using. I'll make your answer as the best solution for now, as I think the issues you highlighted were valid and would help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

fullCalendar has it's own method of switching between views that can be used instead of tabs, as shown below.

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listYear'
            },

            buttonText: {
                today: 'Today',
                month: 'Calendar View',
                listYear: 'List View'
            },

            defaultView: 'listYear',
            defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2016-09-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2016-09-07',
                    end: '2016-09-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2016-09-11',
                    end: '2016-09-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2016-09-28'
                }
            ]
    });

});
</script>
```